# Overlapping elements of storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following code updates the `Label` in my prototype cell. However when the content takes up multiple lines, the `UIImageView` below the `Label` overlaps with it. I have uploaded pics of the storyboard and when the content is updated. How can I ensure that there is a fixed space between the last line of the `Label` and the `UIImageView`? I was under the impression that the spacing to nearest neighbor constraint would solve this but it seems to fix the spacing between the `UIImageView` and the first line of the `Label`.

```
contentText.numberOfLines = 0;
contentText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
contentText.text = text;
[contentText sizeToFit];
```

[image: From StoryBoard]
[image: When populated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup vertical spacing constraint between the label and imageView.

Select your `label` and `imageView`(the one overlapped) and then in Xcode

`Select Editor->Pin->Vertical Spacing`

This would ensure vertical spacing between them.Now as your label would resize according to text the imageView would not overlap instead would maintain a fixed amount of space from the label's last line.

Comment: This solved my spacing problem but now the images don't scale down to the size in my storyboard.

Comment: Are you telling me that you need a fixed size for your imageView ?

Comment: Yeah I want all the images to fit into the `UIimageView` I outlined in my storyboard and I want the `UIImageView` to have a fixed spacing relative to the last line in `Label`.

Comment: but a UIImageView can only display/load one image at a time ! and the fixed spacing issue can be solved like I explained in the answer earlier :)

Comment: Sorry I meant I want the image to fit into the `UIImageView` I outlined in the storyboard. When I pinned the vertical spacing, the image loses the scale I drew in the storyboard and is rendered according the to size of the image.

Comment: For that you need to set the uiimageView mode to scale to fill in storyboard so that it scales the image to fit into the imageview size you provided and if you want to have a fixed size for the imageview you can also setup width and height constraints on the uimageview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62902/discussion-between-rmp2150-and-nofel-mahmood).